# MGADiag.exe reports Tempered Files

Tags: windows-activation

One day, my Windows 7 Ultimate said it's not genuine copy (but I bought it from retail channel). Then I follow the tutorials online to download `MGADiag.exe` to check the Windows Activation status.

It reports the following:

```
Windows Activation Technologies-->
HrOffline: 0x8004FE21
HrOnline: N/A
HealthStatus: 0x000000000001EFF0
Event Time Stamp: 8:10:2013 11:12
ActiveX: Registered, Version: 7.1.7600.16395
Admin Service: Registered, Version: 7.1.7600.16395
HealthStatus Bitmask Output:
Tampered File: %systemroot%\system32\sppobjs.dll
Tampered File: %systemroot%\system32\sppc.dll|sppc.dll.mui
Tampered File: %systemroot%\system32\sppcext.dll|

sppcext.dll.mui
Tampered File: %systemroot%\system32\sppwinob.dll
Tampered File: %systemroot%\system32\slc.dll|slc.dll.mui
Tampered File: %systemroot%\system32\slcext.dll|

slcext.dll.mui
Tampered File: %systemroot%\system32\sppuinotify.dll|

sppuinotify.dll.mui
Tampered File: %systemroot%\system32\slui.exe|

slui.exe.mui|COM Registration
Tampered File: %systemroot%\system32\sppcomapi.dll|

sppcomapi.dll.mui
Tampered File: %systemroot%\system32\sppcommdlg.dll|

sppcommdlg.dll.mui
Tampered File: %systemroot%\system32\sppsvc.exe|

sppsvc.exe.mui
Tampered File: %systemroot%\system32\drivers\spsys.sys
```

What happen to my Windows ? and how to resolve it ?

Comment: Have you run a sfc?

Comment: The `sfc /scannow` log is quite big, I uploaded to: http://dev.raptor.hk/CBS.log

Answer (score 0):

Install [`this update`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971033) to fix these files.

> If the update discovers a tampered file, it tries to restore the file. 
>      This restore may   require a restart.

Comment: Already did. Installation error: 0xc8000247